# How to create a log in and register link in the secondary menu

Tags: users

I am trying to configure my login block on the front page such as that it appears on a separate page. I want the links to this page (that is, login and register) to appear in the secondary menu. I am using Zen with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new entry in the secondary menu and point it to `/user` or `/?q=user`.

Comment: thank you very much. But where can i find the secondary menu? i can't find it in the menu section.